# Swift: fast string building

Tags: string, performance, swift

I was trying to write some Swift code to compare performance with my Obj-C code.

I've got an array (a buffer) of UnicodeScalar that I want to convert to a String object.

```
let range = _peekBuffer[_peekBufferPos .. _peekBufferPos + length]
var retval = ""
for c in range {
    retval += Character(c)
}
return retval
```

The performance is abysmal for a variety of reasons, but I haven't found a better way to construct strings in Swift.  I'm going to try dropping down to NSString and then probably CFString (which is mildly disappointing, since I'm trying to write in pure Swift), but I was wondering if anyone ran into any other options for creating strings 'quickly'.

Comment: use `NSMutableString`. you can't write any useful code with pure Swift.

Comment: If there are specific things you're trying to do that aren't performing well, [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to convert an array of UnicodeScalars to a String, but you can convert UnicodeScalars to an array of Characters and then an array of Characters to String:

```
var characters = [Character]()
for unicodeScalar in range {
  characters.append( Character(unicodeScalar) )
}
return String( characters )
```